# Javascript - Converting a number to two decimal places while keeping zeros

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have number without decimal places and I want to convert it to two decimal places (while keeping zeros) and keep its number type.
I have tried it like this:

```
$scope.invoice_data.form_data.items_shipping_handling = parseFloat(($scope.invoice_data.form_data.items_shipping_handling).toFixed(2));
console.log(typeof $scope.invoice_data.form_data.items_shipping_handling);
```

But it parseFloat doesn't take into account decimal places if they are zeros.
So if I have `2` I want to convert it to `2.00 //number`.
Thank you for your time. I mention that the code is in angular so if it is any angular way of doing it I am open to suggestions.

**Details: I cannot simply use toFixed(2) I need the result to have decimal places but to keep its number format, toFixed() converts it to string. I need it to be of number type!**

Comment: A float (returned from `parseFloat`) does not have a "number of decimal places". That is a display thing - and you already know how to do that `toFixed(2)`. I dont see what your question is?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, but since you need the trailing 0s I am thinking it does not matter what format this display is in right?

Comment: If I use toFixed(2) I convert the number to string I want to keep its format. And I tried this by parsing the string from toFixed() to parseFloat, but something like 2.00 gets returned as 2. I want to get 2.00 and have the number format not string

Comment: @Huangism it matters because the result I use in math calculations.... And I return to the view the result of those calculations as well as the formatted number with two decimal places.

Comment: @Alphonse then when you do the calculation, convert it back to a number or use a different variable. Use the string for display and convert when calculating, or use 2 vars one for displaying and one for calculating

Comment: @Alphonse or whenever you need the 0s in the view, just do the conversion in the html(angular) or you can make a filter to do the same

Comment: @Huangism the problem is that in the view i use a <input type="number"> and by returning a variable as string I get console errors (and I want to keep the input as number to use the step="0.1" property)

Comment: The `value` property of an input - even a `number` input can still be a string. In fact I think it *has* to be.

Comment: @Alphonse does the input need to be type number? If so, you should really reword the entire question and ask for this specific issue, basically detailing what we talked about in the comments. Also adding the input html code and the error you get in console

Comment: @Jamiec it cannot I get an error about this in the console..

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://jsfiddle.net/aLwj6hw0/)

Comment: Also - worrying when you say you use the rounded number in calculations. This is a recipe for disaster usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers dont have a "number of decimal places" - they're internally just a series of 1's and 0's. To *display* a number to a set number of decimal places you can use `toFixed`

```js
var value = 2;
console.log(value.toFixed(2));
```

If you're trying to *round* a number to a set of decimal places one way is to multiply by 100, round it and then divide by 100

```js
var value = 2.123456
var rounded = Math.round(value*100)/100;
console.log(rounded);
```

Comment: right answer - rounding is a _presentation_ issue

Answer (score -2):

*variable*.toFixed(2)

[doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

- List item